# Xtext and pure-e4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext, e4

I'm doing e3 to pure e4 migration of an application that use Xtext editor to provide scripts typing.
It uses the EmbeddedEditor class which is deeply linked to the org.eclipse.ui plugin.
As I can see in a lot of websites it seems that it's not possible to use Xtext editor with a pure e4 app.
Could you confirm that to me ? 
And if it's true, is there a similar framework to write script like Xtext do ?

Comment: If it uses `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` plugins you can't use it in e4. I don't know of an alternative.

Comment: I hoped there was an e4 version of Xtext...Or alternative of EmbeddedEditor.

Comment: Since e4 doesn't define any sort of editor interface or any workspace file system it would be difficult to create a standard e4 version.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do a soft migration of Xtext editor. I'll still use org.eclipse.ui. If I do, i know that it will not be a true e4 pure application but, as long as there is no bugs...Or maybe should I do a mixed e3/e4 application, but is there e4 features that are not available with this mode ?